# Stop thread from working after it fills the queue

Tags: c#, multithreading

To stop The thread based on a flag Finesedequeue In the below thread method I did a loop in the stop button(its purpose is to stop this thread after it fills the queue named _textFromFilesQueue ) and the main problem in this is that my form is freezing

Here is my code:

The Threads Method:

```
 public static bool Finisedqueue ;
    public void  Read(string inputDirectoryPath)
    {

        try
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            Finisedqueue = false;
            Console.WriteLine("thread 1 started");
            if (Form1.IsStarted)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                var dir = new DirectoryInfo(inputDirectoryPath);
                FileInfo[] f = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");
                if (f.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} directory contains {1} Files",inputDirectoryPath,f.Length);
                    int counter = 0;
                    foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in f)
                    {   

                        counter++;
                        var filePath = Path.Combine(fi.DirectoryName, fi.Name);
                        string textFromFile = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                        _textFromFilesQueue.Enqueue(textFromFile);
                        Console.WriteLine("The text inside file number {0} is : {1}",counter,textFromFile);
                       fi.Delete();
                        Console.WriteLine("deleting file number {0} from input folder",counter);


                    }
                    Finisedqueue = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("finished Deleting files");
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Has no files inside it ",inputDirectoryPath);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", excep);
            throw(excep); 

        }
    }
```

The Stop Button Click:

```
        private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        while (!Thread1.Finisedqueue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Queue from First Thread is still Enqueuing data");
        }
        Thread1Timer.Dispose();
        button3.Enabled = true;
        textBox3.Enabled = true;



    }
> the main problem in this is that my form is freezing
```

IF any body can help me in this Thank you very much

Comment: Your form freezing in the `while` loop.

Comment: how can i solve this problem !

Comment: Your StopClick isn't stopping anything, it just hangs until all the work is done.

Comment: You should probably use a BlockingCollection. And Tasks and CancelationTokens and EnumerateFiles and ...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

When busy waiting it is a good idea to sleep, so that you give other threads a chance to execute.

```
while (!Thread1.Finisedqueue)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Console.WriteLine("Queue from First Thread is still Enqueuing data");
}
```

You can also check out the Task class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx which is nice for asynchronous operations such as file IO and is awaitable using the built-in `async/await` functionality.

```
private Queue<string> q = new Queue<string>();
private Task readFilesTask;
public void ReadFiles(string inputDirectory)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(inputDirectory, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var textFromFile = File.ReadAllText(file);
        q.Enqueue(textFromFile);
        File.Delete(file);
    }
}

private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    readFilesTask = Task.Run(() => ReadFiles("//path/to/dir"));
}

private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    readFilesTask.Wait();
    //readFilesTask.Wait(1000); // if you want kill the task after waiting for 1000 milliseconds
    //Enable buttons
}
```

Comment: You could also use Thread.Yield method for a better performance, if you can do that (this can vary based on your .NET version

Comment: can you please give me an example in my situation to change it in my code! thank you